# Suppress StatusBar ignoring onscreen buttons in UWP app on a phone

Tags: c#, windows-10, uwp

In my app I need to suppress StatusBar so I use this.

```
ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().SetDesiredBoundsMode(ApplicationViewBoundsMode.UseCoreWindow);
ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().SuppressSystemOverlays = true;
```

But using this will also suppress onscreen buttons if device (a phone) have them.
Is there any way to suppress just StatusBar? Or at least get buttons panel height?

Answer (score 0):

Replace the lines of code you provided with these:

```
if (Windows.Foundation.Metadata.ApiInformation.IsTypePresent("Windows.UI.ViewManagement.StatusBar"))
{
     var i = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.StatusBar.GetForCurrentView().HideAsync();
}
```